# Populating a grid via autocomplete and posting the results

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have a view where I create a new company.

The company has a number of trades, or which 1 is a primary trade.
So when I enter the trades for that company, I select a trade via autocomplete, and this trade is added to a grid of trades underneath the autocomplete textbox. The grid contains the tradeId as a hidden field, the trade, and a radio button to indicate whether the trade is a primary trade and a remove button.

This is part of a form that contains other company details such as address.
Now I am wondering if I can use knockout and (maybe) jsrender to populate the grid without posting to the server?

When I have filled in the grid AND the other company details, I then want to submit the data to the controller post method.

Normally I use the Html helpers to post values to the controller, but I don't see how I can do that using knockout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Knockout for this. If you have not checked the tutorials out yet then try this [Knockout List and Collections tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections). This should point you in the right direction. What you'll need to do is create a Trade object with observable properties and in a separate knockout view model create an observableArray to store trade objects. For information on posting to the server there are other tutorials in the same location.

```
function Trade(item) {
    var self = this;
    self.tradeId = ko.observable(item.tradeId);
    self.tradeName = ko.observable(item.tradeName);
    self.isPrimary = ko.observable(item.isPrimary);
}

function TradesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // Editable data
    self.trades = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.removeTrade = function(trade) { self.trades.remove(trades) }

    self.save = function() {
         $.post("/controller/action", self.trades);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new TradesViewModel());
```

Comment: Thank you for that, very interesting. Can I post this ViewModel to a method on the controller where I can update the database? If so how?

Comment: @arame3333 Yes of course... I've included a very basic example in the edit. If you want it to automatically post data then you can just make this function a computed variable. At the moment you will need to invoke it manually from a button. `<input type="button" data-bind="click: save" />`

Comment: Ps If you want more control over the Ajax post then use the $.ajax() method. $.post() is just a convenience wrapper method